# Java - (Print distinct numbers)

Tags: java, printing, numbers, distinct

I'm trying to solve this problem:

"Write a program that reads in ten numbers and displays the number of distinct numbers and the distinct numbers separated by exactly one space."

My code at the moment does not save all distinct numbers and at time repeatedly display 0. If anyone can see where my logic has gone wrong, any tip will be helpful. Thank you!

```
public class PracticeProject
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int[] number = new int[10];
    int[] counter = new int[10];
    int numcounter = 0;

    numGen(number);
    numcounter = distNum(number, counter, numcounter);
    dispDist(counter, numcounter);
}

public static void numGen(int[] number)
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++)
    {
        number[i] = rand.nextInt(10);
        System.out.print(number[i] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}

public static int distNum(int[] number, int[] counter, int numcounter)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++)
    {           
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (counter[j] == number[i])
            {
                break;
            }

            if (j == i)
            {
                counter[j] = number[i];
                numcounter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return numcounter;
}

public static void dispDist(int[] counter, int numcounter)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numcounter; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(counter[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: create a map from using your array of input numbers

Comment: Keep random into `Set<Integer>`, which keep only distinct

Comment: You can use set also if dont want to store frequency

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the logic in your `distNum()` method, which was not correctly removing all duplicates from the output array.  Try using this version instead:

```
public static int distNum(int[] number, int[] counter, int numcounter) {
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        boolean isUnique = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < numcounter; j++) {
            if (counter[j] == number[i]) {
                isUnique = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isUnique) {
            counter[numcounter] = number[i];
            numcounter++;
        }
    }
    return numcounter;
}
```

I walk through the array of random numbers, and for each one I scan `counter` to see if the value has already been encountered.  If it be a duplicate, then it does not get added to the unique list.

This method was tested along with the rest of your original code using IntelliJ, and it appears to be working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try put below function .... using Hashmap... Key will be no. and value will be the disctinct time it occured.

```
public void duplicate(int[] a) {

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> h = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        Integer j = (int) h.put(a[i], 1);
        if (j != null) {         // checking if already in hashmap
            h.put(a[i], j + 1);   // if there then incrementing value
        }

    }

    Iterator it = h.entrySet().iterator();  // displaying value you can have you logic here
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `array` to store your counters, you need to set default value, otherwise if your array have multiple `0`, it distinguish by equaling. because the `int array` default values is ***0***.

and you can use `list` or `vector` to store your `counters`.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] number = new int[10];
        int[] counter = new int[10];
        List<Integer> counters = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int numcounter = 0;

        numGen(number);
        numcounter = distNum(number, counters, numcounter);
        dispDist(counters, numcounter);
    }

    public static void numGen(int[] number) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            number[i] = rand.nextInt(10);
            System.out.print(number[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    public static int distNum(int[] number, List<Integer> counters, int numcounter) {
        for (int i : number) {
            if (!counters.contains(i)){
                counters.add(i);
            }
        }
        return numcounter;
    }

    public static void dispDist(List<Integer> counter, int numcounter) {
        for (Integer i : counter) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
```